# How to create view with extra column called Id (primary key) in Db2?

Tags: sql, db2

Could anyone help me to create a view from the table? I am using IBM Db2 on cloud, I have a table with below columns:

[image]

I want to create a view having an extra column **id** as below:

[image]

I need to this column be unique so I think adding a new column as identity. I must mention this view returned a large of data so I need a way with good performance. I have seen some related posts on Stack Overflow, but I found those are for different databases.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You should explain, how you are going to use such an id further. 
You must understand, that while there are a number of ways to enumerate rows "on the fly", such an id for a row will not be permanent. I.e. such a row id may change, when table data is changed (either in this row or in others).

Comment: Hi @MarkBarinstein I am going to call and fetch the records of view from String Boot application(using Curd Repository), I am gonna do the select operation only. We have a scheduled job that will refresh in a day. However, I need an id just for a reference to pass in Curd Repo, I am not going to use it anymore. I don't mind if the id gets a change in the next refresh job.

Comment: Use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYVIEW AS SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER() AS ID, T.* FROM MYTAB T`.

Comment: Hi @MarkBarinstein it works for me. This is what exactly I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `sequence` and call the sequence in as id.

1. Create a sequence in the database
2. Call the sequence in a view and alias it as ID

Creating sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 
MAXVALUE 30 MINVALUE 0   -- As you required
NOCYCLE CACHE 10 ORDER;  -- As you required
```

Calling in query:

```
select sequence_name.NEXTVAL, f_name, i_name, city, country from table;
```

If you do not want to use sequence, you can also so use `ROW_NUMBER()` in your query